# Applications of Prüfer sequence

Tags: graph-theory, trees, applications

Reading a book about a graph theory I found out about [Prüfer's sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence) which converts a labeled tree of $n$ vertices into an array of $n-2$ numbers.

I was actually pretty surprised by this and was curious about it's applications. The couple applications that I came up were:

- archiving the tree
- creating a random labeled tree

and only then I read the application in the wiki page. Now because they have not wrote about archiving a tree, I am curious whether they have missed some other applications.

So are there other applications of the Prüfer code?

Comment: If you count theoretical applications as well then it  allows one to prove that the complete graph on $n$ vertices has $n^{n-2}$ spanning trees (Cayley theorem)

Comment: @Jernej thank you, but it is already written on the wiki page.